# Display HTML string in a frame

Tags: java, html, swing, javafx

I have a string containing HTML. I want to display that HTML content in a frame. I am using this code right now:

```
JEditorPane html=new JEditorPane("text/html", stringhtml);
html.setEditable(false);  
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(html);  
frame.add(scrollPane);
```

The `frame` is a `JFrame` and `stringhtml` is the string containing the HTML.

However this doesn't always work, sometimes the frame remains empty. I know `JEditorPane` doesn't support HTML5 and that I should use Java-FX, but I don't really understand how I should use it after reading the documentation.

Can someone give me an example of do what I need using JavaFX?

Comment: *"sometimes the frame remains empty."* That's a problem in the code that should be fixed before considering porting to Java-FX. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Can someone give me an example of do what I need using JavaFX?"* SO is not a code generation machine, and it is not a help desk. If you want help, make an attempt, & post an MCVE with a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm sorry. It wasn't my intention to be demanding. As for the MCVE I'm retrieving mails using javamail. I get the content of the mail in a string and try to display it as html. The ones that don't get diplayed are the complex mails. Should i post all of that here?

Comment: *"The ones that don't get diplayed are the complex mails."* Uh-huh.. I mistakenly thought you controlled the HTML content and could limit it to HTML 3.2 (the last HTML version that Swing claims to implement). For a 'real world' browser, it'll need a Java-FX `WebView` then, so see [Adding HTML Content to JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).. Recently I embedded a `WebView` into a Swing frame, then realized it needed a lot of other controls to make it a good user experience, which if I coded them in Swing, would become a nightmare ..

Comment: .. to interact with the Java-FX component (since each are on separate threads). As such, if you go the `WebView` route, I strongly suggest going all Java-FX from the start, to avoid problems later.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i tried using a WebView and now all the mails are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/) has information that should help.

```
public WebViewExample extends Application
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
  {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.getEngine().loadContent("<html><body>Hello World :p</body></html>");
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(webView);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: "Shouldn't the GUI creation be on the Java-FX event thread?" AFAIK it is, as shown. The stage is an API argument, just to provide a naïve example.